# Flutter Bloc sending state before event is recieved

Tags: flutter, state, bloc

So, this is weird. I have a bloc setup and a screen that sends events to the bloc and receives states... the problem is the screen is receiving the state before the bloc receives the event... how is this even possible.

Here is the code.

Screen:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    BlocProvider.of<NoteBloc>(context).add(ScreenLoadedEvent(id: noteId));
    print('Screen: Send the screenloadedevent');
    return Scaffold(
      body: BlocBuilder<NoteBloc, State>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is InitialState) {
            print('state initial'); //this never prints... 
            return Container();
          }
          if (state is LoadedState) {
            print('Screen: Recieved state from bloc state.note is ${state.note.title}');
            return SomeWidget();
          }
```

Bloc:

```
class NoteBloc extends Bloc<Event, State> {
  NoteRepo notesRepository;

  NoteBloc({this.notesRepository});

  @override
  State get initialState => InitialState();

  @override
  Stream<State> mapEventToState(Event event) async* {
    if (event is ScreenLoadedEvent) {
      print('Bloc: recieved screenloadedvent');
      note = await notesRepository.fetchNote(event.id);
      yield LoadedState(note);
    }
```

Here is the print that spits out. How is the bloc receiving the event AFTER the screen is receiving the state?? The bloc should only send out the state after it gets the event, right?

```
I/flutter ( 5256): Screen: Send the screenloadedevent
I/flutter ( 5256): Screen: Recieved state from bloc state.note is: null
Reloaded 8 of 757 libraries in 498ms.
I/flutter ( 5256): Bloc: recieved screenloadedevent <-- why is this happening last???
```

Comment: where is this print statement `Screen: Recieved state from bloc state.note is: null` in code?

Comment: Apologies, I was trying to reduce some of the complexity in the code for this example. This print statement is this one: print('Screen: ${state.note.title}');   I'll edit the example.

Comment: Change "State" class name to another name, and try again, Perhaps it is the cause

Comment: @faroukosama do you mean that State is a dart keyword and might clash? The actual state class name in the app is NoteScriptState, I simplified it to just State in the example above. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Well my friend, I tried this for me and didn't get this problem, the arrangement was right for me, try the same thing but without "BlocProvider"

Comment: If it still actual, please post real code to help to solve it